# Is there a way to combine multiple models into the Sklearn PMML Pipeline function?

Tags: python, pmml

I have a series of models that are generated based on Company and Product. and am using the following code:

```
for company in company:

    # 2. For each product
    for product in product:
        predict_cols = ['x1', 'x2']
        target_col = 'y1'

        if product in [1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9]: 
            predict_cols.append('x3')
            cols = ['x4','x1', y1] + predict_cols

        if product in [6, 11, 13, 16]: 
            cols = ['x4','x1', target_y1] + predict_cols

        data = df_sheet1[(df_sheet1.company_id == company_id) &
                        (df_sheet1[target_col]> 0)][cols]
        # 3. Split train and test sets
        target = data[target_col]
        predictors = data[predict_cols]
        
        X_1, X_2, Y_1, Y_2 = train_test_split( predictors, target, test_size=0.2, random_state=123)

        # 4. Train
        clf = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=10)
        clf.fit(X_1, Y_1)
        if product in [1,2,3,4,7,8,9]:
            pipeline_obj = make_pmml_pipeline(clf, active_fields= ['x1','x2','x3'],target_fields=['y1'])
        if product in [6,11,13,16]:
            pipeline_obj = make_pmml_pipeline(clf, active_fields= ['x1','x2'],target_fields=['y1'])
```

sklearn2pmml(pipeline_obj2, 'MODEL_NAME.pmml', with_repr = True)

I get the following error which I assume means that it can only handle one input :
TypeError: The pipeline object is not an instance of PMMLPipeline. Use the 'sklearn2pmml.make_pmml_pipeline(obj)' utility function to translate a regular Scikit-Learn pipeline or estimator to a PMML pipeline

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Your example is invalid - your Python code shows derivation path for `pipeline_obj` variables, but the accompanying exception is about a `pipeline_obj2` variable.

> I get the following error which I assume means that it can only handle one input

The SkLearn2PMML package can handle multiple models, for as long as they are packaged into a single "container" `PMMLPipeline` object.

Comment: Sorry I missed a line and don’t currently have my laptop with me to check. 

I believe at the bottom it should have: pipeline_obj2= pipeline_obj.append

Comment: You should be using the `sklearn2pmml.ensemble.SelectFirstClassifier` meta-classifier for ensembling two elementary classifiers.

Comment: Hey sorry, I can't find any documentation on how to implement this, are you able to give me some code examples or documentation I can look through?